# In Yocto, how do I specify a version restriction of package A to be the current version of package B?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to be able to update my system by installing packages created by Yocto instead of installing the whole image created by it. The objective is to update some software without affecting the system configuration. However, I want to avoid updating a package without updating other runtime dependencies that changed to avoid leaving the system in an inconsistent state.

The approach that I'm following until now is to set version restrictions to package. Suppose I have a layer with recipes A.bb and B.bb that creates packages A and B. I'm using RDEPENDS on A.bb to set package B as a dependency of package A as follows:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = " B (= hard-coded-current-version)"
```

where `hard-coded-current-version` is something like `1.1-r1`. However, what I want is something like:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = " B (= parametric-current-version)"
```

where `parametric-current-version` would be something like `${PE_B}.${PV_B}-${PR_B}`.

How do I specify a version restriction of package A to be the current version of package B?

Comment: Does `version restriction` means that there are more than one version of package A ? You could use `PREFERRED_VERSION_A = "1.1-r1"`` on distro or machine configuration side.

Comment: The package A can be updated to r2 while package B don't change, for example. So it is only necessary to have package A for updating. However, if packages A and B are updated, I can't update package A without updating package B.

Comment: There will be multiple versions of package A, but I want to use each of them with a specific version of package B to assert compatibility. So, I guess PREFERRED_VERSION won't be applicable. Thank you for presenting me the PREFERRED_VERSION variable.

Comment: please follow this link https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_VERSION for more information and example about PREFERRED_VERSION variable. As mentioned `You can use the % character as a wildcard to match any number of characters, which can be useful when specifying versions that contain long revision numbers that could potentially change.`